# How to split a string starting from first digit in python

Tags: python

I'm looking for a python built-in function that will help me to split a string starting from where a digit starts.
For example

```
input: TengGigE0/0/3/4 
output: 0/0/3/4

input TengigabitEthernet 4/3/4/3
output: 4/3/4/3

input: Te0/4/5 
output: 0/4/5
```

How can this be achieved in python, if not in regex ?

Comment: Are you lookin for a solution is is not using regex?

Comment: @Guy I'm looking for optimized solution, I'm not sure if it is regex or python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider the builtin module [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), you could extract from the first digit to the end:

```
import re

m = re.search(r'\d.*', 'TengGigE0/0/3/4')
out = m.group()
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8ucuXY/1)

Or, removing all the leading non-digits:

```
import re

out = re.sub(r'^\D+', '', 'TengGigE0/0/3/4')
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dy2ikv/1)

Output: `'0/0/3/4'`

Another approach with the builtin [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile):

```
from itertools import dropwhile

out = ''.join(dropwhile(lambda x: not x.isdigit(), 'TengGigE0/0/3/4'))
```

Other outputs:

```
# TengigabitEthernet 4/3/4/3
4/3/4/3

# Te0/4/5
0/4/5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the string and split on the index where you encounter a digit.

```
s = 'TengGigE0/0/3/4'

from string import digits

for char in range(len(s)):
    if s[char] in digits:
        print(s[char:])
        break
```

Output:

```
0/0/3/4
```